# Subtitle reordering

Tags: subtitles

A subtitle I downloaded had issues where the beginning of the line is on the bottom and the end of the line is on the top. Like this:

```
                        will be your last day?
                      What would you do if today,
```

How can I edit this so that it will be flipped and I don't wanna edit everything from scratch as I do not have the time for it. I'm asking for a simple solution for this.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a section of the SRT file that contains a line or lines that show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that your problem has been solved or not. This happen with me too and i fixed already

1. download subtitle edit
   https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit
2. open your srt and go to menu "Tools > Sort by > choose another one
3. save your file

if you would like to convert your srt to text just go to menu "File > Export > choose file type you like"

Answer (score -1):

does this happen in just 1 subtitle file??

- Try a different player, I strongly suggest you download K lite codec pack (Mega) from the official [site](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) and install it will Media Player Classic as your default player and give it a try.
- If it still comes up like this then try downloading a new subtitle file.
  Also, open the subtitle file in notepad and inspect it a bit.

Comment: I used VLC and the first thing I did after downloading the sub is open it in notepad and I don't see anything wrong. It just looks how an srt file should look like in notepad. And btw I downloaded the sub from Netflix.

Comment: @khangkhong Did you try k lite codec pack ? btw are you using windows..mention such things in the question.

Comment: I'm using windows. Downloaded the mega version but the sub is still the same.

Comment: Avoid 'codec packs'!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  why to avoid codec packs ??

Comment: Avoid codec packs because they may contain malware, or their hosting site may, also they mess with registry sometimes in very stupid ways, and most times you just need to use VLC.

Comment: I have been using k lite mega codec + Media Player Classic  since 12 years and I never faced any issue, it is the best for playing every format you throw at it and its playback quality is so much better than VLC. Just give it a try sometime and you wont go back to VLC. Don't worry it has no malware, use any application to scan it.